# Filter Github issues closed by a user

Tags: github

Is there way to filter the issues closed by a user.

Referred the below link, but didn't help.

https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

Answer (score 3):

You could [list repository issues](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#list-repository-issues), filtering by `state: closed`.
The answer includes a `closed_by` field that you can use to filter the result set.

Another approach, using [GitHub GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), is possible en though the [Issue object](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#issue) does not have a [`ClosedEvent`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/closedevent/#) field which actually has the `Actor` field with the user details.

GitHub support suggests in [that thread](https://github.community/t/graphql-repo-issues-has-no-closedby-field/13820/3)

```
query commits{
  repository(owner: "rohit-smpx", name:"inno"){
    issues(first: 10, states:CLOSED){
      nodes{
        number
        title
        timelineItems(itemTypes:CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1){
          nodes{
            __typename
            ...on ClosedEvent{
              actor{
                login
              }
              createdAt
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried these but didn't work. `is:issue is:closed closedby:xxxx` and  `is:issue is:closed closed_by:xxxx`

Comment: Exactly, hence my suggestion to try either GitHub API V3 or V4 (graphql)